# Exporting .jar Applet in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet

I have an applet and I can't export it to a runnable jar because it doesn't have a main class( public static void main(String args[]) ) I need a runnable jar because I have a program that has many classes and packages. How do I make this work. If the answer is adding a main method what do I put in the main method?

**Update** I tried to use a normal .jar but still nothing. Here is a reply i sent to better describe what is happening

"I still get the class not found error. I have a .jar that has a "main" folder. Then in the "main" folder I have all my classes. My main class is Render.class so in html i use this code to open the applet:    "

Comment: No, you don't need a runnable jar, if it is meant to just contain a JApplet/Applet. You just need a jar.

Comment: Just to verify: You have a Java applet that you want also to be usable just by running the jar?

Comment: no, I was going to call it from html using...    <applet archive="MyJar.jar" code="mainpackage.MainClass" width="800" height="600">

 
    
</applet>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's an applet it isn't a 'runnable jar'. Luckily, you don't need one. You just need an ordinary jar. Eclipse will make one of those.

Comment: Thank you I'll try that. but can I use the code <applet archive="MyJar.jar" code="mainpackage.MainClass" width="800" height="600">

 
    
</applet>

Comment: I still get the class not found error. I have a .jar that has a "main" folder. Then in the "main" folder I have all my classes. My main class is Render.class so in html i use this code to open the applet: <applet archive="superminer.jar" code="main.Render.class" width="800" height="600"></applet>

Comment: classes don't belong in a 'main' folder. They belong in the directory corresponding to their package name, or in the very top if they have no package.

Comment: Why 'main.Render.class' and not 'main.Render'?

Comment: idk I'll try that and see if it works. Sorry to keep you busy :P

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13493/discussion-between-36redsoxfan-and-bmargulies)

Comment: Can you update your answer to include where the `jar` file will be located?